# jquery not catching selector of input by name

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to toggle between 2 divs and I can't even get through the first challenge... to catch the radiobutton click event with jQuery selector.

```js
$("input[name='radio_btn_options']").on("click", function(){
    debugger;
    alert("1234");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" style="margin:15px" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-secondary active">
        <input type="radio" name="radio_btn_options" id="diagramRB" autocomplete="off" checked> Diagram
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-secondary">
        <input type="radio" name="radio_btn_options" id="listRB" autocomplete="off"> List View
    </label>
</div>
```

I don't get no error message no nothing. Nothing just happens have i done something wrong??

Comment: I've converted your plain code into a stack-snippet. The snippets seems to work just fine!

Comment: My guess, you try to access the element before it is rendered on the page. `console.log($("input[name='radio_btn_options']").length)`

Comment: Seems its working fine, just checked your snippet?? On radio click i can see the alerts.

Comment: Most likely a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Comment: okey it worked when i changed to 'change' event instead of click event